# Implementing stack denoising autoencoder with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I was trying to implement a stack denoising autoencoder in tensorflow. Here is the code I got. It worked with one layer, but when I tried to stack it(by changing the list of parameter n_neuron). It doesn't work anymore. I was trying to debug it for a long time but still couldn't get the answer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Reading MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels

#parameters
examples_to_show = 10 #finally display 10 pic
mnist_width =28
n_visible = mnist_width * mnist_width #input layer
n_neuron = [n_visible,500] #n_visible is input layer size, the numbers after are hidden size neuorn unit nunmbers
corruption_level = 0.3
batch_size=128
train_epochs=10
hidden_size=len(n_neuron)-1
Z=[None]*hidden_size #Estimated output
cost=[None]*hidden_size
train_op=[None]*hidden_size #trainning operation

# X as input for each layer
X = tf.placeholder("float",  name='X') #demensinonality of input is not defined

# set dictionary for all the parameter in the hidden layer
weights_encoder=dict()
weights_decoder=dict()
biases_encoder=dict()
biases_decoder=dict()
for i in range(hidden_size): #initialize variables for each hidden layer
    W_init_max = 4 * np.sqrt(6. / (n_neuron[i] + n_neuron[i+1])) #initialize variables with random values
    W_init = tf.random_uniform(shape=[n_neuron[i], n_neuron[i+1]],
                                minval=-W_init_max,
                                maxval=W_init_max)
    weights_encoder[i]=tf.Variable(W_init)
    weights_decoder[i]=tf.transpose(weights_encoder[i]) #decoder weights are tied with encoder size
    biases_encoder[i]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_neuron[i+1]]))
    biases_decoder[i]=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_neuron[i]]))


def model(input, W, b, W_prime, b_prime): # One layer model. Output is the estimated output
    Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input, W) + b)  # hidden state
    Z = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y, W_prime) + b_prime)  # reconstructed input
    return Z

def corruption(input): #corruption of the input
    mask=np.random.binomial(1, 1 - corruption_level,input.shape ) #mask with several zeros at certain position
    corrupted_input=input*mask
    return corrupted_input

def encode(input,W,b,n): #W,b weights_encoder and biases_encoder, X is the input, n indicates how many layer encode(i.e: n=0: input layer. n=1: first hidden layer etc.)
    if n==0:
        Y = input #input layer no encode needed
    else:
        for i in range(n): #encode the input layer by layer
            Y=tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(input, W[i]), b[i]))
            input = Y #output become input for next layer encode
        Y = Y.eval() #convert tensor.object to ndarray
    return Y

def decode(input,W_prime,b_prime,n):
    if n == 0:   #when it is zero, no decode needed, original output
        Y = input  # input layer
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            Y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(input, W_prime[n-i-1]), b_prime[n-i-1]))
            input = Y
            Y = Y.eval()  # convert tensor.object to ndarray
    return Y

#build the graph
for i in range(hidden_size): #how many layers need to be trained
    Z[i]= model(X, weights_encoder[i],  biases_encoder[i], weights_decoder[i], biases_decoder[i])
    #create cost function
    cost[i] = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(X,Z[i])))
    train_op[i]=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.02).minimize(cost[i])

# Launch the graph in a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize all variables!
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for j in range(hidden_size):  #j start from 0
        encoded_trX = encode(trX, weights_encoder, biases_encoder, j) #Encode the original input to the certain layer
        encoded_teX = encode(teX, weights_encoder, biases_encoder, j) #Also encode the test data to the certain layer
        for i in range(train_epochs):
            for start, end in zip(range(0, len(trX),batch_size), range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size)): #Give all the batches
                input_= encoded_trX[start:end] #take one batch as input to train
                sess.run(train_op[j], feed_dict={X: corruption(input_)})  #trainning step, feed the corrupted input
            print("Layer:",j,i, sess.run(cost[j], feed_dict={X: encoded_teX}))  #calculate the loss after one epoch. Cost should be calculated with uncorrupted data
        print("One layer Optimization Finished!")
    print("All parameters optimized")

#applying encode and decode over test set
    output=tf.constant(decode(encode(teX[:examples_to_show], weights_encoder, biases_encoder, hidden_size), weights_decoder, biases_decoder, hidden_size)) #put the test data into the whole neuron network
    final_result=sess.run(output)
# Compare original images with their reconstructions
    f,a = plt.subplots(2, 10, figsize=(10, 2))
    for i in range(examples_to_show):
        a[0][i].imshow(np.reshape(mnist.test.images[i], (28, 28)))
        a[1][i].imshow(np.reshape(final_result[i], (28, 28)))
    f.show()
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you set n_neuron= [n_visible,600,500], you will find that on the picture, the second row is difficult to recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
n_neuron = [n_visible,500,400] #n_visible is input layer size, the numbers after are hidden size neuorn unit nunmbers
```

This works perfectly for me on my computer. If it does not work for you, please let us know what error you get.

Comment: On my computer the cost is also going down. However I expect that on the picture the second row(which is output of the neuron network) should at least look like the original input. But it doesn't. This will be very obvious if you try n_neuron = [n_visible,784] and n_neuron = [n_visible,784,784]

Comment: Assuming you are trying less neurons: can you try what happens with more neurons, and what happens with more iterations?

Comment: I tried to play with it a lot of times. But it seems only working well when I have one hidden layer.

Comment: Hi,rmeertens. I am stuck with this denoising autoencoder implementation for quite a few days. If it's convenient for you, could you give me some suggestions? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Hey Linchen, What I can suggest you do is start with the 'easiest to learn' case where you put n_visible to n_visible. Then start going to more difficult cases...

Comment: I think I understand the idea of denoising autoencoder. Actually it works perfect with one hidden layer (even with size smaller than input size). But when I start to stack it (using the output of the first hidden layer as the second hidden layer's input), the picture I got just went wrong. I don't know if there is some logic error or something with the implementation of tensorflow.